# Angular $watch on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

Lets say i have an array of animal objects bound to my scope. Each object has a 'name' property and a 'sound' property.

I then $watch the array and set the objectEquality flag to to true (the third argument).

In my view i create a button for each of the animals using an ng-repeat of the animals array. I then pass the click handling function the corresponding animal object.

In the click handler, if i were to update the name of one of the animals, the $watch picks up the change and i can handle it in the listener function.

Now the issue that i am having is that if i were to reassign one of the animal objects with a new object, instead of just changing its property, the $watch does NOT pick up this change. The array of objects has clearly changed yet my listener is not being called.

The following plunkr is of the example i have just outlined:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PHXq32?p=preview

Comment: You can use `$watchCollection`

Comment: Does not work. Here is the plunkr for that.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VLlCNj?p=preview

Comment: My feeling is that it is changing the reference to the object while $watch is looking for attribute changes to the old reference to the object. I could be totally off though.

Comment: Well I didn't notice this before, but your `changeObject` function does not replace anything in the array. It changes the reference of your `animal` variable from an object in the array to the one you instantiate in that function. Also, you should post the broader scope of the problem you're trying to solve by having a `$watch` function in there in the first place. As far as I can tell from the Plunker, you're just assigning your `$scope.animals` to `$scope.result` which doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with AngularJS
First thing - always remember JavaScript is **pass by value**
What does it mean? Lets take two cases primitives, arrays and objects

1. **Primitives** - You just pass the value to the function. So if you pass a variable initialized outside a function as a function argument changes made to the value inside the function does not change the value outside.

   `function testPrimitive(prm){
     prm = prm+1;
   }`

   `var prm = 1;
     testPrimitive(prm);
     console.log(prm) //prm will be`still 1
2. **Object and Arrays** - Here the value passed is the reference of the object. So the question arrises how does changing property of a object passed to a function is reflected and changes do not reflect if the entire object is newly created. Lets take an example.

   `var foo = {id:1, name:'iamfoo'}, bar = {id:2, name:'iambar'};
   //so here two objects are created lets say at some referrence in memory ref1 and ref2 and the //memory location is assigned to foo and bar`

   `function updateObj(o1, o2){
     o1.name='changed'; 
     //the object o1 is not newly created. its only takes the reference and updates the property.
     o2 = {id:3, name:'iamnew'}; 
     // A new object is created in a reference say 'ref3' and the ref3 is assigned to o2.      Note here ref1 still remains the same
   }`

   `updateObj(foo, bar);` //ref1 and ref2 memory location value is passed here

   `console.log(foo);//foo will be {id:1, name:'changed'}
    console.log(bar);
    //bar will be {id:2, name:'iambar'} since bar still has ref1 memory  location value`

In your case you are passing an creating an new object inside the array and assigning the referrence. The referrence will be lost once you are outside the function loop and cannot be used anywhere;
Try  `animal.name ='Billy'; animal.sound='baaaa';` instead inside your function

A nice article about this: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Though I feel these looks like basic things most people are not aware or quite confused with this.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I am aware that primitives are passed by value and objects are passed by reference. But what i did not realize was that even though the object is being passed by reference, it is only a copy of that reference (location). So when you assign a new reference to that object it will not be persisted outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

try passing $index as a parameter to you function and then do

```
$scope.animals[index] = {name:'Billy', sound:'baaaa'};
```

that should do it